# How to list all AD users in the “Add Multiple Users” dialog

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

When using the Add Multiple Users feature in Dynamics CRM 2011, you are presented with a list of AD users to select from, when there's a lot of users, the list is truncated (at least in my experience).

Is there a way to show all users?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no straight forward way for your question. Mean that, in CRM application you can not do this. May be a plugin could help you.

Answer (score 0):

No, but if you are really asking "How can I get all or nearly all my AD users into CRM in one go", then the answer is yes, but not through the GUI.

Use a command line tool like dsget to output the necessary details of the users from AD, including their SAMID.

Use this output to create a csv file with the relevant columns and import the users just like any other data.

Comment: What are the relevant columns for importing users?